# How to loop dcast function in reshape package in R

Tags: r, loops, reshape, lapply

Being a relatively new R user, I have trouble with any looping functions. I have looked at many tutorials but the examples in them are usually very basic and therefore easy to execute. However I need create slightly more complex loops and am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to do so. There are a few related looping questions on here and other forums but none match exactly what I need and though I have tried to adapt other answers for my current problem, I keep running into errors.

I have 2000 .csv files with data tabulated in long-format data (simplified example):

```
solution1    
> sol1     sol2     Istat
> s1       s2       0.435
> s1       s3       0.456
> s1       s4       0.845
> s1       s5       0.234
```

It is basically a summary of pairwise comparisons of 2000 individual solutions that I have, with the similarity between solutions summarised in an 'Istat' value.

I am trying to dcast each of these 2000 .csv files into wide-format table (using the reshape package in R) so they look like (following example above):

```
     s1     s2     s3     s4     s5
s1   NA     0.435  0.456  0.845  0.234
```

I know how to do this just once with a single .csv file:

```
stat.cast <- dcast(solution1, sol2 ~ sol1, value.var="Istat")
```

But I can't seem to work it into into a `for` loop function or even with `lapply`, which seems like it could be a possible solution here too.

The closest I was able to get with a `for` function:

```
 # Get files from directory
loopout = "/Users/jc219806/Documents/Chapter 1/ANALYSES/R work/Istat/last_LoopOut/"
# List of file names inside folder
solutions <- list.files(loopout)
# Read all 2000 files inside
all.data <- lapply(solutions, read.csv, header=TRUE)
# Loop for performing reshape cast function to each listed dataframe
for (i in 1:length(all.data))
  {
  all.cast <- dcast(all.data, sol2 ~ sol1, value.var="Istat")
  }
```

But it keeps giving me the error that it is unable to recognise the "Istat" value from the input - even though it is there in the list of dataframes I have ("solutions" object in code above).

And with the `lapply` function:

```
lapply(solutions, dcast(all.data, sol2 ~ sol1, value.var="Istat"))
```

I get the same type of error:

```
Error: value.var (Istat) not found in input
```

I don't understand why because it is listed in the list of dataframes, as one of the variables in each of the 2000 dataframes. It seems like I am not getting it to loop through each of my 2000 .csv files properly, but I don't know how to fix that. I was also wondering if it were also possible to write the code so that it loops through  binding all the 2000 outputs together according to column names? It's looping crazy.

I hope this is not as complicated a problem as it seems to me to be. Any help (along with some detailed explanations) or useful direction would be massively and sincerely appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I guess it would be `sol1~sol2` to get the expected result you showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would `melt` your "all.data" list and then `dcast` it to a wide form. Something like:

```
## Sample data
set1 <- set2 <- data.frame(sol1 = c("s1", "s1", "s1", "s1"), 
                   sol2 = c("s2", "s3", "s4", "s5"), 
                   Istat = c(0.435, 0.456, 0.845, 0.234))
set2$Istat <- set2$Istat + 1 ## Just to see some different data

all.data <- mget(ls(pattern = "set\\d+")) ## use your actual object

## The reshaping
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(all.data, id.vars = c("sol1", "sol2")), 
      L1 + sol1 ~ sol2, value.var = "value")
#     L1 sol1    s2    s3    s4    s5
# 1 set1   s1 0.435 0.456 0.845 0.234
# 2 set2   s1 1.435 1.456 1.845 1.234
```

If your "all.data" object has names, "L1" will reflect those names, which can be quite convenient in the long run.

Answer (score 5):

You wrote:

```
for (i in 1:length(all.data))
  {
  all.cast <- dcast(all.data, sol2 ~ sol1, value.var="Istat")
  }
```

What you should have written:

```
all.cast <- list()
for (i in 1:length(all.data)) {
  all.cast[[i]] <- dcast(all.data[[i]], sol2 ~ sol1, value.var = "Istat")
}
```

But a more "R-esque" solution would be:

```
all.cast <- lapply(all.data, dcast, sol2 ~ sol1, value.var = "Istat")
```

Hopefully this makes it clear what you did wrong.

Answer (score 4):

"all.data" is a list of dataframes.  To loop over the list, you can use `lapply` and an anonymous function call (just to be clear) and apply `dcast` on that.

```
library(reshape2)
lapply(all.data, function(x) dcast(x, sol1 ~ sol2, value.var="Istat"))
```

Or instead of doing individual `dcast`, the list can be `rbind` to a dataframe with a grouping variable for each list element and then either do `dcast` or `spread` from `library(tidyr)`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
unnest(all.data, group) %>% 
                  spread(sol2, Istat)
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(rbindlist(Map(cbind, all.data, group=seq_along(all.data))),
                 group + sol1 ~sol2, value.var='Istat')
```

#### data

```
all.data <- structure(list(solution1 = structure(list(sol1 = c("s1", 
"s1", 
"s1", "s1"), sol2 = c("s2", "s3", "s4", "s5"), Istat = c(0.435, 
0.456, 0.845, 0.234)), .Names = c("sol1", "sol2", "Istat"), 
class =     "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)), solution2 = structure(list(sol1 = c("s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1"), sol2 = c("s2", "s3", "s4", "s5"), Istat = c(0.42, 0.536, 
0.945, 0.324)), .Names = c("sol1", "sol2", "Istat"), 
class =    "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))), .Names = c("solution1", "solution2"))
```

Comment: I see we're thinking along the same lines with your update. +1 :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto  I was updating when you posted the solution.